# I need help on how to graph $2x-y=6$ I need help on getting the $y$ and $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I need help on how to get the $x$ and $y$ in this situation. please explain how do I put it on the graph and also how to get the $x$ and $y$ all in steps please.

Comment: In this case $y=2x-6$.

Answer (score 1):

To plot the graph of $y=2x-6$ you could do this:

First notice that it has the form $y=ax+b$

which is similar to $y=x$

which is just the identity line.

Then notice that it's multiplied by $a$ this just change the slope (more vertical or maybe more horizontal).

And finally you have $+b$, which just moves the graph up (if $b>0)$ and down if $(b<0),$ respect to $Y-axis$

Answer (score 1):

To plot a linear function like this you only need to find two points on the graph and then connect them. The graph is the line that both points lie on.

So find two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ that satisfy that equation, mark those two points on a two dimensional graph, and then connect them with a ruler (and extend this line past each point).

Hint: Consider what happens when $x = 0$ and $y=0$.

This site does not exist just to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

Any equation in the form $ax+by=c$ can be simplified as follows.
$$ax+by=c$$
$$by=c-ax$$
$$y=\frac{-a}{b}x+\frac{c}{b}$$
Which you graph just like any other equation in the form $y=Mx+B$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the linear function in standard form. First convert it to slope-intercept form. The general form is like this.
$$Ax + By = C \longrightarrow y = mx + b$$
Remember, in slope-intercept form, $m$ is our slope and $b$ is our $y$-intercept.
$$By = -Ax + C$$
$$y = \frac{-Ax+C}{B}$$
$$y = -\frac{A}{B}x + \frac{C}{B}$$
We have converted it to slope-intercept form with $m = -\frac{A}{B}$ and $b = \frac{C}{B}$.

In your example, the function is this.$$2x - y = 6$$
$$-y = -2x + 6$$
$$y = 2x-6$$
Identify $m$ and $b$. $m = 2$ and $b = -6$. At $b$, $x =0$ so draw a point at $(0, -6)$. The slope is $2$, so any change in $x$ will bring about double the change in $y$. So, we can choose another point: $(1, -4)$. ($\Delta x = 1$; $\Delta y = 2$).

Just draw a line connecting those two points and it’s done.